# tag question for sentences including subject "I" and that clause

Tags: tag-questions

Fred claims that mother never let us leave the house without permission when we
were kids, …?
a)did she    b)weren't we   c)didn't she   d)doesn't she

Which on is the answer?
What would be the answer if the subject were "I" (I claim that ...)? Any difference?
If it were "I told you that ...",then what would be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct conclusion for the first sentence would be "doesn't he?", since it refers to what Fred currently thinks.

For "I claim that..."  it refers to I with present tense, so it would be "don't I?", however such a sentence would not be idiomatic: you are making the claim as a part of this sentence, so it's pointless to ask the rhetorical question "don't I?".

For "I told you that...", it refers to I with past tense, so it would be "didn't I?".

Comment: Thanks. Would you please answer the second question too?

Comment: Fred is *typically* a masculine name, leading to "Fred claims [something], doesn't he?"  That aligns with the cultural expectation that there are more Fredericks than Winifreds.  Without establishing the subject's referent, it's *possible* that "Fred claims [something], doesn't she?" is appropriate.